# checking net connection to catch error while mailing in python/flask

Tags: python, flask

I am using python/flask (importing MAIL from flask_mail). Here is a small module of my code.

```
token = s.dumps(email, salt='email-confirm')
t = url_for('confirm_email', token=token, _external=True)
msg = Message('Confirm Email', sender='origrosh@gmail.com', recipients=[email], html=render_template('mail.html', text=t))
link = url_for('confirm_email', token=token, _external=True)
msg.body = 'Your link is {}'.format(link)
mail.send(msg)
```

If I run the code when the Internet connection is off, I get a 'socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution' error. Can  you please tell me how to catch this exception and display something like "Make sure you are connected to the Internet" or something instead?

```
except urllib2.URLError as err: 
    return False
```

Some way to catch the exception like the above (where an attempt is made to access a particular URL) would also be helpful. So, what is the alternative to that when you are using MAIL in FLASK instead.

Also, I would be very thankful if you can also provide a more general solution as I may end up having to tackle similar problems (when the Internet is not connected) later.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's your problem with catching the exception... You know how to catch an exception in Python don't you ??? Also, if you get this error, it's your server that lost it's connection, not the user, so telling the user to "make sure he is connected to the internet" makes no sense at all.

Comment: I do know how to catch exceptions but not this particular one. Also, yeah, in that case, the text could be something else. Basically, I want to control what happens instead of that error turning up.

Comment: Actually if your server's connection is down, chances are your user won't get the HTTPResponse at all... Just saying <g>.

Answer (score 1):

> I do know how to catch exceptions but not this particular one

Well, just like with any exception actually:

```
>>> import socket
>>> try:
...     raise socket.gaierror(3, "wtf")
... except socket.gaierror as e:
...     print "got gaiesocket error %s" % e
... 
got gaiesocket error [Errno 3] wtf
```

If you want to special-case errno 3, just test `e.errno`:

```
>>> e
gaierror(3, 'wtf')
>>> e.errno
3
```

Comment: Another question. This exception (errno 3) occurs only when the server is disconnected from the Internet, right? Else, what other cases?